# Could we be notified when the handler has finished the task? How?

Tags: android, handler

I have used handler to handle the decompress task use the `handler.post(new Decompress())`, I have reserve a looper for this handler. how could we be notified when the task has been finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be notified in the UI thread, then I would create another one `Handler` object in UI thread and keep a reference to it in the thread where you perform the decompress task. When the task is finished, you just send a `Message` to the UI thread using it's `Handler`.

But the most convenient way is to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)